# Using Confuser for Silverlight obfuscation?

Tags: silverlight, obfuscation

Has anyone tried using Confuser to obfuscate Silverlight projects, or know if it is possible to do so?

I tried using it on a dll from a xap, however it ended at a user-defined breakpoint and then gave the following message:

System.NotSupportedException
Message : Version not supported: 5.0.5.0

[Using Silverlight 5 (v 5.0.61118.0)]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confuser does not support Silverlight at the time of writing. The feature has been proposed, and marked as active on the project's [issue tracker](http://confuser.codeplex.com/workitem/8256).

It's open-source software and possibly it would work on Silverlight if the code is altered to detect the Silverlight libraries. There might be issues with XAML renaming, and there would be an issue with datacontexts being set since that uses reflection, but those could be avoided by turning off renaming and using a different obfuscator to that part.